# From where should I start learning python for Image Processing

Tags: python, image-processing, motion-detection

I need to create a **project** which **detect's** the **motion** of an **object** on the screen an **triggers** the **alarm**.
For example if diamond is placed in front of the camera and the position of the diamond is Changed the **alarm/siren** should be **triggered**.
How to implement this with PYTHON and from where should I get started.
Any guidance will be **APPRECIATED** :)

Comment: Your question will get marked flagged by some of the fellows even if the question is right and needful according to you. These are the fellows who think they know too much about python. There are some who will mark it as flagged but not all. So Don't worry about that and so don't delete the question.

Comment: I work as a CV engineer...If you want to learn CV specifically, i am giving you my personal blog `http://afzal-datascience-blog.com` ,it might help you, best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

[Try here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/start-here/)

They also have short pdf manual on getting started with some introductory resources listed.